# Specifying installed native library paths during pypy translate

Tags: python, dynamic-linking, static-linking, pypy, rpython

I am trying to build the latest pypy repo on a Mac machine. One of the needed libraries, libintl, is installed in `$HOME/opt/local/lib`. I run (using a previously built `pypy-c`),

```
pypy-c translate.py -Ojit --ldflags=-L~/opt/local/lib --cflags=-L~/opt/local/lib
```

However, after about half an hour, it stalls with

```
[translation:ERROR]     ld: library not found for -lintl
[translation:ERROR]     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[translation:ERROR]     make: *** [pypy-c] Error 1
[translation:ERROR]     """)
```

So how am I supposed to specify the path for this library? I would assume the same would happen for compiling and executing custom rpython programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### New Environment Variable

Talk about timing — I just added support for this! You can now set a `PYPY_LOCALBASE` environment variable when you translate, e.g.

```
PYPY_LOCALBASE=/Users/tav/local pypy-c translate.py -Ojit
```

It will then add the `lib` and `include` directories inside `PYPY_LOCALBASE` to the library/include paths, i.e. `/Users/tav/local/lib` and `/Users/tav/local/include`.

#### Issues with Fink & Macports

It's been a while since I've used either, but the `gettext` package provided by the package mgmt. systems used to be a source of pain — builds, including CPython, would get contaminated by packages provided by Macports and friends, e.g. http://bugs.python.org/issue7679

#### Translation From Tip Should Now Work on OS X

I've spent the last few weeks fixing up the various edge cases with building PyPy on OS X. And hopefully, as of last night, it should now build with a simple `pypy-c translate.py -Ojit` with nothing except plain old Xcode.

Just pull the current tip/master with `hg` or `git` and you should be good to go... let me know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Tav, I tried to build the tip, but I don't think I got to the point to test whether LOCALBASE would help because I got a translation error. I've filed an issue. Once that is resolved I will find out whether this works. I will let post the result here.

Comment: It seems there is another OS X specific error. I have submitted ticket number 672: https://codespeak.net/issue/pypy-dev/issue672 .

Comment: Thank you, it is fixed in the tip.